# Tough Algebraic Simplification

Tags: calculus, statistics

I'm having an hard time solving the following expression. In order to get you tuned this is an extract of an Integral containing the multiplication of two Normal Distributions. This is very similar to the related convolution problem without using Fourier Transform.

The initial expression after completing the square is :

$$
\frac{\left(x - \dfrac{\mu_f \sigma^2_g + \mu_g\sigma^2_f}{\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g}\right)^2}{ 2\,\dfrac{\sigma^2_f\sigma^2_g}{\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g}} + \frac{\dfrac{\mu_f^2 \sigma^2_g + \mu_g^2\sigma^2_f}{\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g} - \left(\dfrac{\mu_f \sigma^2_g + \mu_g\sigma^2_f}{\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g}\right)^2}{ 2\dfrac{\sigma^2_f\sigma^2_g}{\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g}}
$$

Then we should be able to simplify further to this expression :

$$
\frac{(x-\mu_{fg})^2}{2\sigma^2_{fg}}+\frac{(\mu_f-\mu_g)^2}{2(\sigma^2_f + \sigma^2_g)}
$$

Any thoughts ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the mess inside $(x-mess)^2$ to be $\mu_{fg}$.
Simply define the denominator to be $2\sigma_{fg}^2$.
All you have left is the numerator of the second term.  For that, you have to put it over a common denominator, expand, and see what happens.